# Inline inheritance of an abstract class in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance

In Java, we can inherit an interface inside a method like that:

```
public Class myClass {
    void myMethod() {
        myInterface listener = new myInterface() {
            public onClick() {
                //code goes here
            }
        };
        setListener(listener);
    }
}
```

---

In C++; assuming I have an abstract class:

```
class myInterface {
    public:
        myInterface();
        virtual ~myInterface() {};
        virtual void onClick() = 0;
}
```

I try to inline inherit this abstract class like below but it gives errors:

```
myClass::myMethod() {
    myInterface *listener;
    listener = new myInterface() {
        virtual void onClick() {
            //some code here
        }
    };
    setListener(listener);
    delete listener;
}
```

All of the examples and tutorials I find on internet explain inheritance via subclassing. But how I can inline inherit this abstract class inside myClass::myMethod()?

Comment: There's no such thing in C++. And usually no need for it when you can pass a function pointers/lambdas/callables as parameters.

Comment: you can't. The good news is that in c++ library functions usually accept lambdas/functions rather than objects

Comment: `setListener(listener); delete listener;` - not good, you will likely have a pointer to a deleted memory somewhere after this. Use a `std::shared_ptr` instead of a manual memory management.

Comment: It's a different language with different semantics, idioms and patterns. If you are an experienced Java programmer, I would recommend reading the Effective (Modern) C++ series from Scott Meyers, if you are a beginner I would recommend reading a good introductory book, e.g. The Tour of C++.

Comment: Your Java code is also subclassing, but the subclass doesn't have a name. (It has in the program itself, but it's not accessible to you.)

Comment: @MarianSpanik Thanks I know that. I put delete line there to just stay away from memory leak comments.

Comment: You can define a local, unnamed class in C++ as well. `struct : myInterface { void onClick() {} } listener;` creates an object `listener`. But I don't think you can create that directly on the heap. A named local class *can* be used to create something on the heap, of course.

Answer (score 2):

## The short answer is: you cannot.

There is no secret keyword or compiler feature you missed.

C++ is not Java. There are different patterns, idioms and syntactic tricks the C++ people use to achieve the same effect. You will need to read a good book or tutorial to get them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the C++ way:

## include

```
#include <boost/signals2.hpp>

class notifier {
public:
  void notify(int i) {
    handlers(i);
  }
  boost::signals2::connection add_listener(std::function<void(int)> listener) {
   return handlers.connect(std::move(listener));
  }
  void remove_listener(boost::signals2::connection &connection) {
    handlers.disconnect(connection);
  }
private:
  boost::signals2::signal<void(int)> handlers;
};
...
notifier n;
n.add_listener([](int i) {
  std::cout << i << std::endl;
});
n.notify(100);
```

Comment: That looks pretty similar. Can we implement the same thing without boost?

Comment: @Rancs You could for sure just implement your signal library. In the simplest case when you have only one callback at a time, you could just use a std::function. There are also other signal libraries than boost.

Comment: Unfortunately I am working on C++99. Is there an equivalent?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using C++11 you can adopt lambdas for that:

```
class myLambdaListener : public myInterface{
    public:
        myLambdaListener(const std::function<void()>& func) : mFunction(func){}
        void onClick() override {if(mFunction) mFunction();}
    private:
    std::function<void()> mFunction;
}

myClass::myMethod() {
    myInterface *listener;
    listener = new myLambdaListener([](){
            //some code here
    });
    setListener(listener);
    //delete listener; - do not delete here
}
```

Comment: Is there a C++99 equivalent of that?

Comment: @Rancs the lambdas were introduced in C++11 and everyone had a sigh of relief because before them you had to use really weird stuff to get same behavior. You can look at the boost's lambda, they are working with C++99